# How to say I am an interdisciplinary person

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am wondering if there is a way to describe a person who studies in interdisciplinary(e.g. art+science).

I want to make a sentence like "....becoming a XXX person"

Thanks

Comment: You're a *polymath*.

Comment: What do you mean LOL

Comment: It's not one word, but I like [Renaissance man/woman](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/renaissance-man-or-woman) "a highly cultivated man (or woman) who is skilled and well-versed in many fields of knowledge, work, etc., as in the arts and sciences" Collins

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to rephrase "I am an interdisciplinary person"

> I am a multidisciplinary person.
>
> [Multidisciplinary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/multidisciplinary)(Cambridge Dictionary) involving different
> subjects of study in one activity:
>
> I am a multiscious person.
>
> [Multiscious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiscious)(Wiktionary) (obsolete, rare) Having much or varied
> knowledge.

Other words you can use

> polymath, omnibus, panoramically versed in multiple disciplines,
> scopious, patchwork of multiple disciplines.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it is okay to write `I am a multidisciplinary person.` in my SOP?

Comment: Choose whatever suits you. "I am a multidisciplinary person", "I studied multiple disciplines", "I am versed in multiple disciplines". Ask others also.